# .Net 4.0 Owin Authentication Example

Tags: .net, authentication, owin

Does anyone know the reference page for implementating Owin Authentication for .Net 4.0 Web application?

I could only find the examples for .Net 4.5. Unfortunately my application was build on .Net 4.0.

I would appreciate for any resources.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need .Net 4.5 as you need System.Security.Claims which was added in 4.5

Comment: Thanks. What authentication can i use in .net 4.0?

Comment: Depends on the model you are using for obtaining identities. If they are external, IdentityProviders you can use WIF (Windows Identity Foundation) 1.0 which requires .Net 3.5 and above. It is a bit old though.

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead an upgrade the application framework and create your own custom owin middleware which I have done in my existing application.